# Deprecated binding, what is the new way to do it?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This binding is deprecated and you are not supposed to use generics anymore. What should I do instead?

```
BindableProperty.Create<ImageGallery, IList>(
                view => view.ItemsSource,
                default(IList),
                BindingMode.TwoWay,
                propertyChanging: (bindableObject, oldValue, newValue) => {
                    ((ImageGallery)bindableObject).ItemsSourceChanging();
                },
                propertyChanged: (bindableObject, oldValue, newValue) => {
                    ((ImageGallery)bindableObject).ItemsSourceChanged(bindableObject, oldValue, newValue);
                }
            );
```

Answer (score 5):

You define the type as a parameter of the `Create()` method like this:

```
public ImageGallery MyImageGallery
{
    get { return (ImageGallery)GetValue(MyImageGalleryProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyImageGalleryProperty, value); }
}

public static BindableProperty MyImageGalleryProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(MyImageGallery), typeof(ImageGallery), typeof(IList), default(IList), BindingMode.TwoWay,
    propertyChanging: (bindableObject, oldValue, newValue) => 
    {
        ((ImageGallery) bindableObject).ItemsSourceChanging();
    },
    propertyChanged: (bindableObject, oldValue, newValue) => 
    {
        ((ImageGallery) bindableObject).ItemsSourceChanged(bindableObject, oldValue, newValue);
    });
```

Comment: Hey Dennis! Thanks for the answer, but there seems to be a problem. Under propertychanged it says it can't convert object to IList for oldvalue/newvalue. And also, could you ELI5?

Comment: I messed up the parameter order. Can you test if it works now? For "propertyName", add the name you wish. I'm not sure what `view => view.ItemsSource` does and how to add it here.

Comment: It is better to use `nameof(propertyName)` then to use a basic string.

Comment: Still sadly get "Can't convert object to IList at this last line "   ((ImageGallery) bindableObject).ItemsSourceChanged(bindableObject, oldValue, newValue);"

Comment: Are you sure you _can_ cast `binableObject` to `ImageGalery`? How does `bindableObject` look like?

Comment: Yes! I'm sure, bindable object is just an xamarin basic class, can post it if you want but it isn't anything custom made. It works in the deprecated version, but would like to update it to the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I have my properties in my Custom Renderers, which shouldn't be deprecated

```
public static readonly BindableProperty SearchTextProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SearchText), typeof(string), typeof(MyCustomClass), string.Empty);

public string SearchText
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(SearchTextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SearchTextProperty, value); }
}
```